# Gmail Filter Based on Contact Label

Tags: search, filter, gmail

I have a bunch of contacts associated with a label in gmail. I would like to set up a filter to label or delete all messages not associated with those contacts in the label. Has anyone found a way to do this?

Example https://snipboard.io/wLvuZt.jpg

Comment: Maybe this post about [handling](https://support.google.com/contacts/answer/30970?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) a group of Contacts.

Comment: @ConstantinKonstantinidis they are in a group, I am trying to create a filter for emails not in a contact group

Comment: The language of the documentation might be confusing. The title says "Group" but the execution says "label".

Comment: @ConstantinKonstantinidis again, can you post how to use that in a filter, nothing in that documentation link discusses that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First create an email to the group (no need to send it) as described [here, under "Use groups in Gmail"](https://support.google.com/contacts/answer/30970?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en#zippy=%2Cemail-a-group). Then copy-paste the list of emails to create a filter for multiple emails in the format `from:{email1, email2, ...}`, as described [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en).

Here's the step-by-step procedure:

1. In gmail Compose a new message
2. In the To: field type the name of the Group (aka the label)
3. Press Tab - this will expand the list of recipients
4. Press Ctrl-A to select all recipients (or click the first recipient to select it, then Shift-click the last recipient to select all recipients)
5. Copy the recipients with Ctrl-C
6. In the Search mail field enter `-from:{LIST}`, where `LIST` is the list of emails you copied (you can paste it with Ctrl-V)

The `-` is because you asked for "all messages **not** associated with those contacts in the label".

The `{...}` is an "OR" operator.

Comment: I am testing this now. While I was hoping to use the user labels it looks like that is not possible directly.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there's a way to use those directly.

Comment: @ChrisHough So will you accept my answer?

Comment: Sorry about that, I lost track of this on in my inbox.

Comment: This is really unfortunate; if it's not obvious, it should be noted that as soon as the contact group changes, your filter will be out of date and either including people who are no longer part of the group, or missing people who are, or both.

Comment: @EzekielVictor There was no mention of saving a filter. If you redo steps 1-6, you will always get an up-to-date search.

Comment: In the question title: "set up a filter"

Comment: Pity this is just a workaround for something that should be a built-in feature.